# ZeroMQ PUB/SUB with epgm loses a lot of message if have multiple publisher

Tags: c++, udp, zeromq, multicast

ZeroMQ 3.2.4 and C++ API, with multicast PUB/SUB using epgm://239.192.1.1:5555, both send and receive high watermark are set to 100, with default recovery interval and rate.

There are 4 nodes, same hardware, all in the same subnet and vlan, the publish rate is < 1KB/second (although there are other network traffics going on, the boxes are not stressed with network io).

If only one of the nodes is publishing then it works fine, but if I let more than node publishes, message loss start to appear. It looks like the more publisher, the more data loss.

With all 4 nodes publishing, I see message loss every minute. Is this normal for pgm/upd multicast? I would think in the same LAN udp multicast should be much more reliable.